# Rf_allocVector only allocates and does not zero out memory

Tags: r, c, rcpp, rcpp11

Original motivation behind this is that I have a dynamically sized array of floats that I want to pass to R through Rcpp without either incurring the cost of a zeroing out nor the cost of a deep copy.

Originally I had thought that there might be some way to take  heap allocated array, make it aware to R's gc system and then wrap it with other data to create a "Rcpp::NumericVector" but it seems like that that's not possible - or doable with my current knowledge.

However and correct me if I'm wrong it looks like simply constructing a NumericVector with a size N and then using it as an N sized allocation will call R.h's Rf_allocVector and that itself does not either zero out the allocated array - I tested it on a small C program that gets dyn.loaded into R and it looks like garbage values. I also took a peek at the assembly and there doesn't seem to be any zeroing out.

Can anyone confirm this or offer any alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked this `rcpp` but that is a function from the C API of R -- whereas the Rcpp API offers you its constructors which *do* in fact set the memory tp zero:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector goodVec(int n) { return NumericVector(n); }")
> sum(goodVec(1e7))
[1] 0
>
```

This creates a dynamically allocated vector using R's memory functions. The vector is indistinguishable from R's own. And it has the memory set to zero
as we use `R_Calloc`, which is documented in [Writing R Extension](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/) to setting the memory to zero. (We may also use `memcpy()` explicitly, you can check the sources.)

So in short, you just have yourself confused over what the C API of R, as well as `Rcpp` offer, and what is easiest to use when.  Keep reading documentation, running and writing examples, and studying existing code. It's all out there!

Comment: Thanks so much for the welcome! Ahh I must've missed the part where we Calloc but having tested it (which I really should've done immediately) its plainly calloced. Is there anything to worry about if I use the R.h Rf_allocvector call inside a Rcpp codebase behind extern C? Or moreover is there an easy way to allocate a (large) array of memory inside Rcpp that can be passed back to R via its base pointer address?

Comment: Why would you want to alloc yourself when you have `Rcpp` and its vectors, matrices, list, ... objects that are R objects?  Your design choice seem odd, but a short comment box is not the place to discuss this.  Basically all design have been made by now, I would ask on `rcpp-devel`. (And yes plain C++ STL alloc is also possible by again then you get C++ containers and have no need for `*alloc()` either.) Lastly, if my answer helps your question it is customary to upvote (click on 'up'-triangle) and/or accept (click on 'tick') it.

Comment: My apologies, definitely a helpful answer and I think my upvote will come around once I hit 15 reputation. I definitely want to take Rcpp as a fixed object and I only wonder if I can construct a solution within the confines that you guys and Rcpp have set out for me.

Comment: As for why I want to alloc myself, I just want to avoid zeroing since I want to use a pretty sizeable chunk of memory, like 10 or so allocations of 2^32-1 bytes, so like 170gb of RAM and even though testing has shown that the calloc is relatively fast, it clocks in at 18 seconds for a 2e8 size array of doubles, I'm not knowledgeable enough to know whether the OS pays the price for me on every page fault. Also just curiousity somewhat as well. With C++ stl allocs I have to pay a copy price on exit which I'd also like to avoid

Comment: We have an attribute `no_init` you can set to not init. Personally I do not use it but I recall you can.  And you still haven't upvoted which you can with any reputation level.

Comment: https://imgur.com/VPxc8mh <- sorry I really can't upvote. Thanks for the no_init function, looks perfect!

For future me: Something like this works perfeclty
`Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector goodVec(int n) { return no_init(n); }")`

Comment: My bad, I confused upvote and accept.  Glad you're set now.  The rcpp-devel list is still good (and low volume!) so come and lurk for a bit.